# K&R c book section 5.2 getint example

Tags: c, pointers

In the section 5.2 getint example, I got something unusual which is not easy to understand and some questions as well

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define SIZE 5
#define BUFSIZE 100
char buf[BUFSIZE];
int sp = 0;
int getch(void);
void ungetch(int);
int main(){
    int n, array[SIZE],getint(int *);
    for (n = 0; n < SIZE && getint(&array[n]) != EOF; n++)
            printf("the %d index is %d\n", n, array[n]);
    //int i;
    //for (i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
    //    printf("the %d index is %d\n", i, array[i]);
}
int getint(int *pn){
   int c, sign;
   while(isspace(c = getch()))/* skip white space  */
           ;
   if (!isdigit(c) && c != EOF && c != '+' && c != '-'){
       ungetch(c);
       return 0;
   }
   sign = (c == '-')? -1:1;
   if (c == '+' || c == '-'){
       c = getch();
   }
   for (*pn = 0; isdigit(c); c = getch())
       *pn = 10 * *pn + (c - '0');
   *pn *= sign;
   if (c != EOF)
       ungetch(c);
   return c;
}
int getch(){
    return (sp > 0)? buf[--sp]:getchar();
}
void ungetch(int s){
    buf[sp++] = s;
}
```

I compile it with cc, and run it:
when I type the following:

```
& ( * ^
```

I got the result:

```
the 0 index is 594377088
the 1 index is 21914
the 2 index is 594376288
the 3 index is 21914
the 4 index is -91537120
```

which is totally a meaningless result;

whereas the following one:

```
897 647 908 223 456
```

I got the expected result:

```
the 0 index is 897
the 1 index is 647
the 2 index is 908
the 3 index is 223
the 4 index is 456
```

There are some points I think worth discussion: from the book it says getint will return EOF for end of file, 0 for not a number and a positive value for a valid number, but when I type something * & $, which is not a number, it will run into ungetch(c) and return 0, until the n is no longer less than the length of the array, I think this example has a pitfall, so anyone could give some idea? many thx!

Comment: It returns `0` and the value at `array[n]` remains uninitialized so it prints garbage.

Comment: yeah, but I reckon it should not push back to the buffer when these non-number come up, otherwise it run into the loop, until n is equal to SIZE

Comment: So you are asking why do they call `ungetch(c);` when a non-digit is found? I don't know. You would think they would want to discard the bad input, not save it for next time.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, but When I tried to remove ungetch(), it does NOT work either, coz the n is already increased, and array[n] is filled with garbage value

Comment: I guess the point of the exercise (it's been a looooong time since I read K&R C) is to use the value returned by `getint()`. If it is EOF, there is no more data and you should break the loop. If it is `0` then there is bad input and I guess it is up to you to consume it and decrement `n`. Else it is valid and you should print it.

Comment: At first glance, I assume it would work, coz it is from the book, the very basic book from learning C, but as I dive into the example, some unexpected happened...One thing I need to mention is: the main function and getint function are separated in the book, I combine them together to make them work, coz I want to justify them, but the it turn out to get something else, I guess I need to modify it, thx for your reply!